# PHP and SQL Save checkboxes as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have written the below to read in data from a radio button (var1) and some checkboxes (var2)

```
   require('config.php');

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!$con)
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

  $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
  $var1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $var1 );
  $var2 = $_GET['var2'];
  $var2 = mysql_real_escape_string( $var2 );  

  $running_total = 0;
  $last_update = "SELECT * FROM $db_tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysql_query($last_update);

 $insert_query = "INSERT INTO $db_tablename (var1, var2) ";
  $insert_query .= sprintf( "VALUES('%s', '%s')", $var1, $var2);

  $insert_result = mysql_query($insert_query);
  if(!$insert_result) {
    die('insert query failed' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_close($con)
```

The input html looks like...

```
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="value1">Test 1</input>
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="value2">Test 2</input>
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="value3">Test 3</input>
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="value4">Test 4</input>

<input type="checkbox" name="var2" value="checkbox1">CB 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="var2" value="checkbox2">CB 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="var2" value="checkbox3">CB 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="var2" value="checkbox4">CB 1</input>
```

Everything works as expected and but as var2 allows for multiple checkboxes to be selected I would like to save multiple values.  I realise I need to do this as an array but I cant work it out.

Can anyone help or have a solution or example they can point me to?

Answer (score 2):

it would be `var2[]` as the `name` and view the results as

```
foreach($_POST['var2'] as $checkedItem)
{
    echo $checkedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The html:
`

```
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="value1">Test 1</input>
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="value2">Test 2</input>

<input type="checkbox" name="var2[]" value="check" /> CB 1
<input type="checkbox" name="var2[]" value="check" /> CB 2
```

`

and the SQL :

`Array $_POST['var2'] contains the checkboxes.`

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of var1 to "var1[]", and change the name of var2 to "var2[]"...

```
 $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
 $var2 = $_GET['var2'];
 echo count($var1);
 echo count($var2);
```

Gl mf

Comment: the radio buttons (var1) dont need to have the `[]` as its only a single value